# setReadable(true) doesn't work after setReadable(false)

Tags: java, file-io

I am testing that a method I have written is throwing a file exception. I am triggering the exception by setting the read permissions on the file to false

```
     File f = new File(unreadableFile);
     f.setReadable(false);
     // Run test
     f.setReadable(true);
```

The problem is that the f.setReadable(true) is not setting the permissions back to what they should be. I have another test which tests the normal mode of operations, and it always fails because f.setReadable(true) didn't restore the file to what it was before the exception test was run. I have checked the permissions on disk, and it is wrong.

Comment: Debug step 1: Have you tried running the program as root/administrator?

Comment: Check the return value, from the JavaDocs *true if and only if the operation succeeded. The operation will fail if the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname. If readable is false and the underlying file system does not implement a read permission, then the operation will fail.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the docs

> **Returns true if and only if the operation succeeded**. The operation will fail if the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname. If readable is false and the underlying file system does not implement a read permission, then the operation will fail.

Check the return value and check if you have permissions to do the operation. The operation is much like delete() and can fail if the you do not have permissions.